# Appium - setting Desired Capabilities in both terminal and test code

Tags: iphone, selenium, testing, automation, appium

I am trying to set some *appium* desired capabilities in the terminal window so that I can, for example, run my tests against different simulator devices:

```
Terminal: $ appium --device-name 'iPhone 6'
```

However, I am have to setup desired capabilities in my actual code, so I have a valid instance of *IOSDriver*.  I use this code:

```
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.3");
capabilities.setCapability("app","../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LightAlarm.app");      
driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

When I run my tests I get an error that deviceName is not being set:

```
The following desired capabilities are required, but were not provided: deviceName
```

However, my terminal *appium* server is all setup correctly:

> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.0 (REV dc30dae9e8fe8c85eeea707dbdbd60350fdff55b)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
>   info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"deviceName":"iPhone 6"}
>   info: Console LogLevel: debug

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: Did you try to add this ? - `capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","your device name");`

Comment: Hi there. Yeah I am looking to avoid having to stipulate the deviceName capability within the code (want to pass it in via the terminal/command line)

Comment: Yes I understand but as far as I know appium does not understand it until you set device name as capabilities..

Comment: You can also try to give device name from appium UI view.

Comment: Tried adding: 
  capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPad 2"); 
And now the iPad 2 opens each time rather than the iPhone 6 that I set in the terminal window... so looks like it doesnt seem to solve the issue.

Comment: and what is happening if you set capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", iPhone 6")

Comment: In that case the iPhone 6 opens as required.  However, I need to be able to pass in iPhone 6 for one run of the test suite and then iPad 2 for another run. i.e. looking to parameterise the running of tests using terminal

Comment: I see.. will let you know if get solution for that..